# Importing symbols into CL-USER (for "iterate")

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a way to import all (exported) symbols from a package to a package that already exists, e.g. CL-USER?

Specifically, I'd like to use [iterate](https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) with minimum friction, so it'd be nice if its keywords would be accessible right at startup, without creating a project-specific package.

(Or how are people using iterate in general?)

Comment: one can import packages symbols, but one needs to make sure that symbols are not producting conflicts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(use-package :iterate)` will make the current package use the iterate package.

I'm not sure how other people use iterate, but in general, I always start projects in a new package, not in cl-user, so I think it's better to bite the bullet and start new project files off with `(defpackage ... (:use :iterate))` if you want to refer to iterate symbols without package prefixes.

Comment: thanks!!! yeah, for actual projects "defpackage" seems to be the way to go, this is more for one-off programming problems like Advent of Code (... although I'm slowly convincing myself that being able to load dependencies quickly might be worth it for those, too :))